# Typearea setting except for frontmatter

Tags: front-matter, typearea

Is it possible to get a page layout for a document with typearea package EXCEPT for frontmatter (the cover of my thesis), which should be a classic book-oneside documentclass?

my current code (simplified) is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,italian,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[headinclude = true, footinclude=false]{typearea}

\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} %sillabazione
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algoritmo}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{listingsutf8,multicol}

\usepackage{natbib}     
\usepackage{setspace}

\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}


\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\input{./beginEnd/title.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\typearea[2mm]{12}
\recalctypearea

\mainmatter

\input{./chapters/chapter01_introduzione.tex}
\input{./chapters/chapter02_movementepathfinding.tex}

\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{./beginEnd/biblio}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT:

I managed to set my custom DIV and BCOR settings only after the title page and the table of content in the following way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,italian,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{typearea}

\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} %sillabazione
\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\thechapter\ #1}{}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algoritmo}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{listingsutf8,multicol}

\usepackage{natbib}     
\usepackage{setspace}

\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{table}{chapter}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{bookmarksnumbered}


\linespread{1.5}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\input{./beginEnd/title.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\KOMAoptions{DIV=12,BCOR=2mm,headinclude=true,footinclude=false}
\recalctypearea
\pagestyle{fancy}

\mainmatter

\input{./chapters/chapter01_introduzione.tex}
\input{./chapters/chapter02_movementepathfinding.tex}

\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{./beginEnd/biblio}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}

\end{document}
```

For pages after the table of content it obviously work, but calling \usepackage{typearea} already loads some default values for DIV and BCOR, so the title page and the table of content are already affected.
Instead, what I would like to achieve is having these two pages with the same top and bottom margin ratio as defined by the default latex book class (which should be 1:1, instead of KOMAscript's 1:2). Is there a way to say: "start KOMAscripting my pages only from this particular point"?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you stick to `typearea`? Otherwise I suggest the use of `\newgeometry` from `geometry` package, with a new page issued, but that should be done anyway, if frontmatter is concerned

Comment: thanks, I edited my question. Well, I like the simple way to define the page proportion of typearea using DIV instead of declaring explicitely the margins with geometry, so I'd like to stick with it. Is it a bad choice?

Comment: According to the manual, you can change the format by `\typearea[BCOR]{DIV}` and `\recalctypearea`

Comment: uh! I missed that part! ok it works, but there's something wrong with the way the header lines in chapters and  in toc is rendered: it is shorter than it should be, like its length refers to the standard layout size. Is it a conflict between typearea and fancyhdr? I updated the code, it's now the full version

Comment: `fancyhdr` and the `typearea` are not contradicting per se, but sometimes, it is better to use the header/footer utilities from `scrpage2` package as well as the `scrbook` class instead.

Comment: I managed to solve the header issue by setting \pagestyle{fancy} only after \recalctypearea. thanks!

Comment: it seems that I spoke too soon. Question updated

Comment: @breathe0 if you want to use `typearea` you should use the `KOMAscript` bundle equivalent class to `book`: `scrbook`. In the other hand, the covers should compose like document apart.